# Seeing no speedup from Cython

Tags: python, python-3.x, cython, cythonize

I'm trying to use Cython to speed up some expensive Python for loops in some numerical code, but have run into an issue where I'm seeing almost no speedup, and think I may have to cythonize a lot more of my code than I had hoped.

As an example, let's say I have the following two functions that have been cythonized, and are part of a larger class:

```
def update(self, double[::1] state_data, double[::1] sensor_data, double sigma):
    cdef int i
    cdef int N = state_data.shape[0]
    
    for i in range(N):
        self.output[i] = self.process_sensor_data(state_data[i], sensor_data, sigma)

def process_sensor_data(self, double current_state, double[::1] sensor_data, double sigma):
    cdef int i
    cdef int N = sensor_data.shape[0]
    cdef double x
    cdef double y
    
    for i in range(N):
        x += self.do_something(current_state, sigma)
        y += self.do_something_else(sensor_data)

    return min(x,y)
```

As seen above, the `update()` function takes in some numpy arrays (`double[::1]`) and a floating point number, and then runs a for loop that calls the `process_sensor_data()` function. The `process_sensor_data()` function then runs its own for loop, which calls two additional functions called `do_something()` and `do_something_else()`, that have been defined somewhere else in the class.

Now let's assume that I can fully cythonize the `do_something()` function, and can thus define it as a fast `cdef` function with a function header such as,

```
cdef double do_something(self, double current_state, double sigma):
    ...
```

but I'm not able to cythonize the `do_something_else()` function (e.g. maybe it calls some functions from the numpy or scipy libraries). Would this imply that the for loops inside `process_sensor_data()` and `update()` would still run at similar speeds to vanilla Python for loops, and not see much of a speedup from Cython?

Put another way, if I cythonize a for loop similarly to what was done above, but there are some function calls and/or calculations inside the for loop that cannot be cythonized (i.e. if Cython's html annotation output shows some yellow code lines in the for loop), does this mean that I won't see much of a speedup when using Cython?

From my own experiments, this unfortunately seems to be the case, but I wanted to make sure that I'm not going crazy. In my code I have a function that takes about 20 seconds to execute in Python, but still takes about 20 seconds to execute after I've tried to cythonize the slow for loops. Having spent quite a few hours going down the rabbit hole of trying to cythonize as many of the variables and functions that are being called within the for loops as possible, I'm starting to think it would be simpler and more readable to implement the class in C++. Any help or guidance would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: "Would this imply that the for loops inside process_sensor_data() and update() would still run at similar speeds to vanilla Python for loops, and not see much of a speedup from Cython?" - depends a bit on what you mean by that, but they're outer loops, so Cythonizing them is a lot less important than Cythonizing inner loops.

Comment: Implementing this in C++ isn't likely to produce a better speedup unless you can use C++ for the NumPy/SciPy functions you weren't able to Cythonize. Even then, if the NumPy/SciPy functionality was already written in C, it might not help much.

Comment: Usually in this scenario crossing bondaries are expensive, if you need to call numpy and for this it has to convert native data to python objects you'll face some overhead, if you could call the C version of the numpy then it would be faster but I dont really knwo if this is possible

Comment: Take a look here https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/numpy_tutorial.html#numpy-tutorial#numpy-tutorial it seems possible to call numpy from cython with no object conversion overhead

Comment: Thanks @geckos, that page has good examples for working with numpy arrays using typed memoryviews and still being able to keep cython code fast, but unfortunately it doesn't seem to talk about using numpy functions and still being able to keep cython code fast (in the loop example they have to re-write `np.clip()`).

Comment: Oh, sorry I didn't see the np.clip example. If you can use C I would go with C, but just because I'm much used to deal with C than with cython, I found numpy C API. Using pure C you have control over python objects creation (which is somewhat automagical in cython), so you can offload your for to C code and call numpy directly from C. If "check your pointers" is my commandment while coding in C, "check you references count" would be my first commandment while dealing with python from C. Good luck! :) https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/c-info.html

Comment: In theory, if you import numpy and your our extension module you should have both C codes loaded and dynamic liked to python interpreter, calling numpy from your extension should be like calling C from C, keep a third eye open for PyObject *Py<Type>_From(..) functions as they would signal objects creation

Answer (score 1):

Cython isn't always faster, especially if you continue using Python datatypes instead of C datatypes.  Also, be aware that conversions between Python and C datatypes can happen implicitly in Cython, and can be expensive.

You could also take a look at numba's nopython decorator, and pypy3.

Comment: I've looked at numba, which is great for non-class functions, but trying to `jit` Python classes is a real headache and makes the code less readable. I've also tried pypy3, but it doesn't seem to work with some python libraries that I use regularly (e.g. `rospy`). After trying and failing with numba and pypy3, cython kind of feels like the "last hope" at trying to write fast numerical/scientific computing code in Python. However, after seeing that cythonized loop speeds aren't improved if they have numpy and scipy function calls in them, it seems like fast Python code may not be possible :(

Comment: Did you try a profiler?  Maybe the hotspot is someplace inobvious?

Comment: Yup, 95% percent of the processing time takes place in a single function which has been identified.